# SystemVerilog dist constraint

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I'm missing something in how to setup a dist constraint.  I'm trying to get an equal weight between two ranges [0:31] and [32:65535].  I've set up a simple test:

```
class data;
  rand bit [15:0] field1;
  constraint c_f1 { field1 dist {[0:31] := 1, [32:65535] := 1};}
endclass

module testbench;
   
  initial begin
    data test_h;
    test_h = new();
    
    repeat(10) begin
        assert(test_h.randomize());
        $display("field1 = %h", test_h.field1);
    end
  end

endmodule
```

However, I'm seeing most values > 32.  What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: EDA Playground copy:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9H9V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:/` operator instead of the `:=` operator.  Change:

```
  constraint c_f1 { field1 dist {[0:31] := 1, [32:65535] := 1};}
```

to:

```
  constraint c_f1 { field1 dist {[0:31] :/ 1, [32:65535] :/ 1};}
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.5.4 *Distribution*.

> The :/ operator assigns the specified weight to the item or, if the
> item is a range, to the range as a whole. If there are n values in the
> range, the weight of each value is range_weight / n .

This gives more values between 0-31:

```
field1 = 0012
field1 = 001f
field1 = 000f
field1 = a138
field1 = 0018
field1 = 001c
field1 = 9d48
field1 = 0009
field1 = 85bf
field1 = f930
```